# How to use javascript change function to toggle a paragraph?

Tags: javascript

I want to toggle an input via a checkbox. Here's the code:

### css:

```
.moveaway{ position:absolute;top:-999rem;}
```

### html

```
<p>
<label><?php _e('Setup Template')?></label>
<input class="check-toggle" name="toggle" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php echo $template ? 'checked="checked' : '';?> />
</p>
<p id="template-input" class="<?php echo $template ? '' : 'moveaway'?>">
<lable for="template-name">Template Name</lable>
<input id="template-name" type="text" name="template-name"  value="<?php echo $tamplate; ?>" />
</p>
```

### javascript:

```
$("input.check-toggle").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("p#template-input").attr('class','');
  }else{
    $("p#template-input").attr('class','moveaway');
    $("input#template-name").val(0);
  }
});
```

The above code works when the template-name input field is empty. When the template-name field value is set, the wrapper `p#template-input` gets merged in to the p which contains the check-toggle input.

I don't understand how the change function made this. I would like to learn how to get the result that the p#template-input can be toggled by the checkbox.

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle.com for us, looks like your code is right, but I would cache the references before apply the function, that way don't matter if they have inside changes, it will still referenced in your var, that you can get inside the closure from change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes in your code and it works.

Look the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U4vQr/).

So first I've changed the `<p>` to `<div>`, it is better to change position from blocks then inline ones, but you can still change it's property on CSS, to keep using `p` or from `div` to still in the line, even put inside the `p`.

Then for *class* I've used the `addClass` and `removeClass`, is better then change it attributes.

It worked as you see in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U4vQr/) the *template-input*.

Like my comment earlier, the cached method:

```
var $templateInput = $("div#template-input");
var $templateName = $("input#template-name");
$("input.check-toggle").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $templateInput.removeClass('moveaway');
  }else{
    $templateInput.addClass('moveaway');
    $templateName.val("0");
  }
});
```

Will run even fast, and the result is same. You can see the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/U4vQr/2/).

Comment: Thanks! it works! but the template-input div initially loaded. Can I have it initially loaded with "moveaway" class?

Comment: yes, I just extract your php code from it: `class="<?php echo $template ? '' : 'moveaway'?>"` or you can just add `class="moveaway"`, will work too.

Comment: thanks, I figured out why it doesn't initially loaded as moveaway-- the val(0) sets the value and saved. so my code treated 0 as the $template name. Now I only need to save it as null.

Comment: Here the demo http://jsfiddle.net/U4vQr/4/ and if you want null val, you just change 0 to "" and will work